# How to debug route not working in OCP 3.4

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I encounter an issue many times, fixed it by recreating the problem app, but I still want to know how to debug and what cause this issue.

For example:
I created a new app jenkins persistent application in my master, I'm able to curl then endpoints IP address in Node/Master, but not able to curl the application exposed IP/hostname address. Sometimes, I just need to remove the application then re-create again, this problem will be fixed, but this time I really want to know how to fix it without re-create, followed the article in https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/sdn_troubleshooting.html to debugging, and I'm pretty sure the DNS is working, just let me kknow if I need to provide any more information to here. Thanks.

Here is my svc description output:

```
 # oc describe svc/jenkins
    Name:           jenkins
    Namespace:      developer
    Labels:         app=jenkins-persistent
                template=jenkins-persistent-template
    Selector:       name=jenkins
    Type:           ClusterIP
    IP:         172.30.78.168
    Port:           web 80/TCP
    Endpoints:      10.128.0.97:8080
    Session Affinity:   None
    No events.
 # oc get svc
    NAME           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
    jenkins        172.30.78.168   <none>        80/TCP      1h
    jenkins-jnlp   172.30.87.38    <none>        50000/TCP   1h


# curl http://10.128.0.97:8080
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
# oc get oauthclient
NAME                           SECRET                                                                 WWW-CHALLENGE   REDIRECT URIS
cockpit-oauth-client           user7IjHLvwuclbrHeVmi2pslHpSbmQuI3ePqjAHbLSS0aNBekio2aqDM3iBbx33Qwwp   FALSE           https://registry-console-default.com.cn,https://jenkins-developer.com.cn

# curl 172.30.78.168:8080
curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.30.78.168:8080; No route to host

# curl 172.30.78.168
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer

# curl jenkins-developer.com.cn
curl: (7) Failed connect to jenkins-developer.com.cn:80; Connection refused

# oc describe route
Name:           jenkins
Namespace:      developer
Created:        2 days ago
Labels:         app=jenkins-persistent
            template=jenkins-persistent-template
Annotations:        <none>
Requested Host:     jenkins-developer.paas.com.cn
              exposed on router ose-router 2 days ago
Path:           <none>
TLS Termination:    <none>
Insecure Policy:    <none>
Endpoint Port:      web

Service:    jenkins
Weight:     100 (100%)
Endpoints:  10.128.0.97:8080
```

Comment: Jenkins service says it is listening on port 80. You are using 8080. Have you tried port 80?

Comment: It's working if curl the port 80, and it makes sense  because my service port is 80, but the target port is 8080, so I should access the service IP use 80 port, but the container is using 8080 port. So when I access to jenkins-developer.com.cn, it should be using 80 port, but I'm  unable to access it.

Comment: Did you create a route? How is it defined? The service IP is not accessible outside of the cluster, you need to create a route to do that.

Comment: Yes, I did. That's the key problem, the route is not working, but I don't know why and how to debug it, even I tried to re-create the route, but it doesn't help. I'll update my route configure file to my above.

Comment: How did you create the route? Did you use your own definition, or did you use ``oc expose svc/jenkins``. What do you get for ``oc describe route/jenkins``? What do you get for ``oc get endpoints``?

Comment: Does your hostname ``jenkins-developer.paas.anim.odw.com.cn`` resolve to an IP from machine you are running curl?

Comment: I created the route in webUI, I already updated my route description in question output. and Here is my endponts output: 
# oc get endpoints
NAME           ENDPOINTS           AGE
jenkins        10.128.0.97:8080    2d
jenkins-jnlp   10.128.0.97:50000   2d

Comment: Yes, it is able to resolve my hostname jenkins-developer.paas.anim.odw.com.cn,  I tried running the curl in my masters and nodes server, all of them are saying connection refused. But all of them are able to resolve my hostname to IP.

Comment: Does your hostname for the web console resolve to the same IP address? What port is the web console running on?

Comment: It's able to resolve to the same IP address, I use tcpdump command confirmed that and it's connecting to port 80 when I access the Jenkins url.

Comment: What is the error you get when you access ``jenkins-developer.paas.com.cn``. In the above logs where showed connection refused, you used ``jenkins-developer.com.cn`` which isn't the same. If the same IP and port is used for web console, you shouldn't be getting connection refused.

Comment: sorry, I don't want to past my real domain name to here, so I did some changes when I paste the information to here. Sorry for the confusion. The domain name is jenkins-developer.paas.com.cn, I know it shouldn't be getting connection refused in normal, and most of the time to fix this problem is recreate the application use the same way then it will work, but that no make any sense. So I'm trying to figure out what kind of problem causes this issue.

Comment: If both the web console and the hostname for your exposed route map to the same IP and port, then they are hitting the same OpenShift router. That router is not going to give back connection refused. If it doesn't know what to do with a hostname it will response with a HTTP Service Unavailable error. If you are getting connection refused on one, it suggests that some network router or proxy before that point is somehow blocking it.

Comment: Hi @GrahamDumpleton, I found out why the route is not working for me. After I add a new route for jenkins-developer.paas.com.cn, it didn't update haproxy configure file successfully for some unknown reason. I restart my router container, now it reloaded all the settings into haproxy. Now the problem is fixed. Really appreciate your help here. Thank You!